# Parse variables within string

Tags: php, string, variables, variable-variables

I'm storing some strings within a `*.properties` file. An example of a string is:

> sendingFrom=**Sending emails from {$oEmails->agentName}**, to {$oEmails->customerCount} people.

My function takes the value from `sendingFrom` and then outputs that string on the page, however it doesn't automatically parse the `{$oEmails->agentName}` within. Is there a way, without manually parsing that, for me to get PHP to convert the variable from a string, into what it should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can modify your `*.properties`, here is a simple solution:

```
# in file.properties
sendingFrom = Sending emails from %s, to %s people.
```

And then replacing `%s` with the correct values, using [sprintf](http://php.net/function.sprintf.php):

```
// Get the sendingFrom value from file.properties to $sending_from, and:
$full_string = sprintf($sending_from, $oEmails->agentName, $oEmails->customerCount);
```

It allows you to separate the logic of your app (the variables, and how you get them) from your presentation (the actual string scheme, stored in `file.properties`).

Comment: Ah, now that is a clever idea! Thank you :)

Comment: I like this method as well. If you ever change your variable names you wont have to modify your file also.

Comment: That's perfect. I have a function which outputs the message with some extra formatting. I've just used `vsprintf` to take my arguments (from 3 onwards) and output. Clean and simple. Awesome idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative.

```
$oEmails = new Emails('Me',4);
$str = 'sendingFrom=Sending emails from {$oEmails->agentName}, to {$oEmails->customerCount} people.';

// --------------

$arr = preg_split('~(\{.+?\})~',$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i+=2) {
    $arr[$i] = eval('return '.substr($arr[$i],1,-1).';');
}
$str = implode('',$arr);
echo $str;
// sendingFrom=Sending emails from Me, to 4 people.
```

Answer (score 1):

as others mentioned eval wouldn't be appropriate, I suggest a `preg_replace` or a `preg_replace_callback` if you need more flexibility.

```
preg_replace_callback('/\$(.+)/', function($m) {
     // initialise the data variable from your object  
     return $data[$m[1]];
}, $subject);
```

Check this link out as well, it suggests the use of `strstr` [How replace variable in string with value in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-replace-variable-in-string-with-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eval with all the usual security caviats

Something like.

```
$string = getStringFromFile('sendingFrom');

$FilledIn = eval($string);
```

Comment: If only there was an `eval_vars` function.

Comment: There are plenty of security issues related to `eval`. For instance, if someone manages to modify `file.properties` he can do very bad things as php will run the code. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: @idiqual, thats what the security Caveats are.  However just don't use it is probably a better Caveat.