# How can I replace a variable in a string with the value in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have string like this in database (the actual string contains 100s of word and 10s of variable):

```
I am a {$club} fan
```

I echo this string like this:

```
$club = "Barcelona";
echo $data_base[0]['body'];
```

My output is `I am a {$club} fan`. I want `I am a Barcelona fan`. How can I do this?

Comment: [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: my string contain 20 variable like this. need i use str_replace() fn 20 times?

Comment: preg_replace is what you are looking for.

Comment: You could actually remove `{` and `}` from the string and just use double quotes around it to get the values stored in those variables (if I've understood what you are actually doing): `echo "My var's value is $var";`. This is VERY bad however. Probably it's better to have an array which stores those values, and use a `for` to replace them.

Comment: `{$club}` is valid PHP syntax for a double quote string interpretation. use this to your advantage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing variables in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197348/replacing-variables-in-a-string) - also there is http://php.net/get_defined_vars

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr). It will translate parts of a string.

```
$club = "Barcelona";
echo strtr($data_base[0]['body'], array('{$club}' => $club));
```

---

For multiple values ([demo](https://eval.in/88384)):

```
$data_base[0]['body'] = 'I am a {$club} fan.'; // Tests

$vars = array(
  '{$club}'       => 'Barcelona',
  '{$tag}'        => 'sometext',
  '{$anothertag}' => 'someothertext'
);

echo strtr($data_base[0]['body'], $vars);
```

Program Output:

```
I am a Barcelona fan.
```

Comment: my string contain 20 variable like this. need i use str_replace() fn 20 times?

Comment: That would be the easy way out. You can also use a combination of associative arrays, and a loop. See my code above.

Comment: @messifan With this solution, make sure to remember to update your associateive array every time you add another variable into a template.

Comment: ok, thanks. $array should be like this array('{$club}' => "Barcelona") double quotes producing error for me

Comment: -1 (ideally) But for multiple times. So this answer allows to inject variables as text. To overcome this, use http://php.net/strtr

Comment: @hakre - In your edit, I see the benefit of using `strtr` in the multiple-value case. But I don't see why you also changed to using `strtr` in the first (single-value) case. Isn't the result the same as the (slightly) simpler `str_replace` code you removed?

Comment: I've realized the dollar sign `$` is not necessary. I can set inside the text template "{club}" and it works. A bit easier for the final user

Answer (score 8):

```
/**
 * A function to fill the template with variables, returns filled template.
 *
 * @param string $template A template with variables placeholders {$variable}.
 * @param array $variables A key => value store of variable names and values.
 *
 * @return string
 */

public function replaceVariablesInTemplate($template, array $variables){

 return preg_replace_callback('#{(.*?)}#',
       function($match) use ($variables){
            $match[1] = trim($match[1], '$');
            return $variables[$match[1]];
       },
       ' ' . $template . ' ');
}
```

Comment: Best solution without use the global variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest the [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function.

Instead of storing `I am a {$club} fan`, use `I am a %s fan`, so your [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) command would go like:

```
$club = "Barcelona";

echo sprintf($data_base[0]['body'],$club);
```

Output: *I am a Barcelona fan*

That would give you the freedom of use that same code with any other variable (and you don't even have to remember the variable name).

So this code is also valid with the same string:

```
$food = "French fries";

echo sprintf($data_base[0]['body'], $food);
```

Output: *I am a French fries fan*

```
$language = "PHP";

echo sprintf($data_base[0]['body'], $language);
```

Output: *I am a PHP fan*

Comment: This is a useful technique, when it is convenient to provide the replacement value(s) that are specific to one string. Note that this would not be convenient for OP - nor for anyone else who has a language-translation dictionary that they wish to apply to a large number of sentences. For example, if there are three sentences `.. $a .. $b`, `.. $c .. $b ..`, and `..$c .. $a .. $b`, there is no convenient way to substitute values into all three sentences. (Where all the `$a` should become the same translated string.)

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This answer still gets upvotes, so people need to be aware that there's a **security vulnerability in the naive interpolation technique present in the below code snippets**. An adversary could include arbitrary variables in the input string which would reveal information about the server or other data in the runtime variable register. This is due to the way the general expression search is performed in that it finds any arbitrary variable name pattern, and then uses those variable names verbatim in the subsequent `compact` call. This causes clients to control server-side behavior similar to `eval`. *I'm leaving this answer for posterity.*

---

You are looking for nested string interpolation. A theory can be read in the blog post *[Wanted: PHP core function for dynamically performing double-quoted string variable interpolation](http://thehighcastle.com/blog/21/wanted-php-core-function-for-dynamically-performing-double-quoted-string-variable-interpolation)*.

The major problem is that you don't really know all of the variables available, or there may be too many to list.

Consider the following tested code snippet. I stole [the regex from Mohammad Mohsenipur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-can-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-string-with-the-value-in-php/15065619#15065619).

```
$testA = '123';
$testB = '456';
$testC = '789';
$t = '{$testA} adsf {$testB}adf 32{$testC} fddd{$testA}';

echo 'before: ' . $t . "\n";

preg_match_all('~\{\$(.*?)\}~si', $t, $matches);
if ( isset($matches[1])) {
    $r = compact($matches[1]);
    foreach ( $r as $var => $value ) {
        $t = str_replace('{$' . $var . '}', $value, $t);
    }
}

echo 'after: ' . $t . "\n";
```

Your code may be:

```
$club = 'Barcelona';
$tmp = $data_base[0]['body'];
preg_match_all('~\{\$(.*?)\}~si', $tmp, $matches);
if ( isset($matches[1])) {
    $r = compact($matches[1]);
    foreach ( $r as $var => $value ) {
        $tmp = str_replace('{$' . $var . '}', $value, $tmp);
    }
}
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: To clarify, this technique is useful if you have an unknown set of global variables that you wish to substitute into strings. If the set of substitutions is known beforehand, then a straightforward string substitution (with an array of from/to pairs) is more straightforward (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match_all('#\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#', $q, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER));
{
    foreach ($matches as $m)
    {
        eval('$q = str_replace(\'' . $m[0] . '\', $' . $m[1] . ', $q);');
    }
}
```

This matches all $variables and replaces them with the value.

I didn't include the {}'s, but it shouldn't be too hard to add them something like this...

```
if (preg_match_all('#\{\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}#', $q, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER));
{
    foreach ($matches as $m)
    {
        eval('$q = str_replace(\'' . $m[0] . '\', $' . $m[1] . ', $q);');
    }
}
```

Though it seems a bit slower than hard coding each variable. And it introduces a security hole with eval. That is why my regular expression is so limited. To limit the scope of what eval can grab.

I wrote my own regular expression tester with Ajax, so I could see, as I type, if my expression is going to work. I have variables I like to use in my expressions so that I don't need to retype the same bit for each expression.

Comment: Given how easy it would be to make a mistake and open a security hole (as you mention), I don't see any justification for using `eval` simply to accomplish string substitution.

Comment: True, but there might be a use for something like my answer. The answer above is much better than mine for this purpose. This was just what I came up with 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I've found these approaches useful at times:

```
$name = 'Groot';
$string = 'I am {$name}';
echo eval('return "' . $string . '";');
```

```
$data = array('name' => 'Groot');
$string = 'I am {$data[name]}';
echo eval('return "' . $string . '";');
```

```
$name = 'Groot';
$data = (object)get_defined_vars();
$string = 'I am {$data->name}';
echo eval('return "' . $string . '";');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
$club = "Barcelona";

$string = 'I am a {$club} fan';

preg_match_all("/\{\\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/", $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $var_name) {
    if (!isset($GLOBALS[$matches[1][$key]]))
        $GLOBALS[$matches[1][$key]] = 'default value';
    $string = str_replace($var_name, $GLOBALS[$matches[1][$key]], $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple parser that replaces {$key} with a value from a map if it exists.

Use it like:

```
$text = templateWith('hello $item}', array('item' => 'world'...));`
```

My first version is:

```
/**
 * Template with a string and simple map.
 * @param string $template
 * @param array $substitutions map of substitutions.
 * @return string with substitutions applied.
 */
function templateWith(string $template, array $substitutions) {
    $state = 0; // forwarding
    $charIn = preg_split('//u', $template, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $charOut = array();
    $count = count($charIn);
    $key = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $count) {
        $char = $charIn[$i];
        switch ($char) {
            case '{':
                    if ($state === 0) {
                        $state = 1;
                    }
                break;
            case '}':
                if ($state === 2) {
                    $ks = join('', $key);
                   if (array_key_exists($ks, $substitutions)) {
                        $charOut[] = $substitutions[$ks];
                   }
                   $key = array();
                   $state = 0;
                }
                break;
            case '$': if ($state === 1) {
                        $state = 2;
                      }
                  break;
             case '\\':    if ($state === 0) {
                           $i++;
                           $charOut[] = $charIn[$i];
                       }
                 continue;
             default:
                 switch ($state) {
                    default:
                    case 0: $charOut[] = $char;
                        break;
                     case 2: $key[] = $char;
                        break;
                   }
         }
    $i++;
    }

    return join('', $charOut);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following snippet is (partly) usefull for someone.

```php
/**
 * Access an object property using "dot" notation
 *
 * @param  object  $object
 * @param  string|null  $path
 * @param  mixed  $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function xobject_get(object $object, $path, $default = null) {
    return array_reduce(explode('.', $path), function ($o, $p) use ($default) { 
        return is_numeric($p) ? $o[$p] ?? $default : $o->$p ?? $default; 
    }, $object);
}

/**
 * Access an array's property using "dot" notation
 *
 * @param  array  $array
 * @param  string|null  $path
 * @param  mixed  $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function xarray_get(array $array, $path, $default = null) {
    return array_reduce(explode('.', $path), function ($a, $p) use ($default) { 
        return $a[$p] ?? $default; 
    }, $array);
}

/**
 * Replaces placeholders from a string with object or array values using "dot" notation
 *
 * Example:
 * "The book {title} was written by {author.name}" becomes "The book Harry Potter was written by J.K. Rowling"
 *
 * @param  array|object  $data
 * @param  string  $template
 * @return string
 */
function render_template($data, string $template) {
    preg_match_all("/\{([^\}]*)\}/", $template, $matches); 
    $replace = [];
    foreach ($matches[1] as $param) { 
        $replace['{'.$param.'}'] = is_object($data) ? xobject_get($data, $param) : xarray_get($data, $param); 
    }
    return strtr($template, $replace);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for getting a variable name like:

```
$data_base[0]['body'] = preg_replace_callback(
    '#{(.*?)}#',
    function($m) {
        $m[1] = trim($m[1], '$');
        return $this->$m[1];
    },
    ' ' . $data_base[0]['body'] . ' '
);
```

Attention: This code I wrote is for `class($this);`. You can declare a variable into the class. Then use this code for detecting the variables and replace them like:

```
<?php
    class a {

        function __construct($array) {
            foreach($array as $key => $val) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }

        function replace($str){
            return preg_replace_callback(
                '#{(.*?)}#', function($m) {$m[1] = trim($m[1], '$'); return $this->$m[1];},
                ' ' . $str . ' ');
        }

    }

    $obj = new a(array('club' => 3523));

    echo $obj->replace('I am a {$club} fan');
```

Output:

```
I am a 3523 fan
```

Comment: Just tried your code on string _I am a {club} fan_ (without `$` sign) - got the following: **PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /tmp/p.php on line 3**

Comment: @AleksG i told in answer this code is for class you can't use it out of class

Comment: I've hacked your code about a bit and the problem I've had is that the variables defined like $club are out of scope for the callback function so I end up getting `Undefined variable: $club`

Comment: It still wouldn't work correctly.  Try with string _I am a {$0} fan_.  Make sure you use the correct regex for a php variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) PHP function.

```
<?php
    $club = "Barcelona";
    echo $string = preg_replace('#\{.*?\}#si', $club, 'I am a {$club} fan');
?>
```

Comment: But this will replace all variables with $club

Comment: @Dipesh the OP needs to replace each variable with its corresponding value.  You're clearly misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score -1):

For your case, honestly, I do not see a reason not to use eval :)
Here is some extra way to define your variables if they are too into your database:

```
$my_variable_name = 'club'; //coming from database
$my_value = 'Barcelona'; //coming from database
$my_msg= 'I am a {$club} fan'; //coming from database

$$my_variable_name = $my_value;  // creating variable $club dinamically
$my_msg = eval("return \"$my_msg\";"); // eating the forbidden fruit
echo $my_msg; // prints 'I am Barcelona fan'
```

This code is fully tested and working with php 7.
But if you allow your users to define such strings into your database, better don't do it.
You should run eval only with trusted data.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
$club = "Barcelona";
$var = 'I am a {$club} fan';

$res = preg_replace('/\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/e', "$$1", $var);
echo "$res\n";
```

It's a one-line `preg_replace`.

With PHP 5.5, `/e` modifier is deprecated. You can use a callback instead:

```
$club = "Barcelona";
$var = 'I am a {$club} fan';

$res = preg_replace_callback('/\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/',
                             create_function(
                                 '$matches',
                                 'extract($GLOBALS, EXTR_REFS | EXTR_SKIP); return $$matches[1];'),
                              $var);
echo "$res\n";
```

Note that this uses a hack of importing all global variables. This may not be exactly what you want. Possibly using closures would be a better idea.

Comment: eval is a very bad suggestion

Comment: @David: I know, this is why I wrote that it's a bad thing to do.

Comment: If it is a bad thing to do is there any point in even posting it? Or perhaps it should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @JacobTomlinson Just because something is a bad thing to do, doesn't mean that it won't accomplish what you need.  As long as you understand _why_ it is a bad thing to do and understand _how_ to protect yourself against it, there is not reason not to use a feature in a language.  Afterall, if it's really so bad, why is still not deprecated?

Comment: Yes I appreciate your point. But speaking of deprecated the `/e` modifier has been deprecated and so I receive the warning `The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead` when running your new code.

Comment: `create_function` is also a similar bad suggestion like using `/e`. Just saying. I stumbled over it once badly because it's actually `eval`. Prevent to use that function at all cost.