# Replacing variables in a string

Tags: php, variables

I am working on a multilingual website in PHP and in my languages files i often have strings which contain multiple variables that will be later filled in to complete the sentences.

Currently i am placing `{VAR_NAME}` in the string and manually replacing each occurence with its matching value when used.

So basically :

`{X} created a thread on {Y}`

becomes :

`Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow`

I have already thought of `sprintf` but i find it inconvenient because it depends on the order of the variables which can change from a language to another.

And I have already checked [How replace variable in string with value in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-replace-variable-in-string-with-value-in-php) and for now i basically use this method.

But i am interested in knowing if there is a built-in (or maybe not) convenient way in PHP to do that considering that i already have variables named exactly as X and Y in the previous example, more like $$ for a variable variable.

So instead of doing str_replace on the string i would maybe call a function like so :

```
$X = 'Dany';
$Y = 'Stack Overflow';
$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y}';

echo parse($lang['example']);
```

would also print out :

`Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow`

Thanks!

**Edit**

The strings serve as templates and can be used multiple times with different inputs.

So basically doing `"{$X} ... {$Y}"` won't do the trick because i will lose the template and the string will be initialized with the starting values of `$X` and `$Y` which aren't yet determined.

Comment: Also see [second option in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065420/199364) which uses [strtr](https://php.net/strtr), to avoid needing a loop. [That was added to the accepted answer of the link mentioned in this question, at a later time.]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm going to add an answer here because none of the current answers really cut the mustard in my view. I'll dive straight in and show you the code I would use to do this:

```php
function parse(
    /* string */ $subject,
    array        $variables,
    /* string */ $escapeChar = '@',
    /* string */ $errPlaceholder = null
) {
    $esc = preg_quote($escapeChar);
    $expr = "/
        $esc$esc(?=$esc*+{)
      | $esc{
      | {(\w+)}
    /x";

    $callback = function($match) use($variables, $escapeChar, $errPlaceholder) {
        switch ($match[0]) {
            case $escapeChar . $escapeChar:
                return $escapeChar;

            case $escapeChar . '{':
                return '{';

            default:
                if (isset($variables[$match[1]])) {
                    return $variables[$match[1]];
                }

                return isset($errPlaceholder) ? $errPlaceholder : $match[0];
        }
    };

    return preg_replace_callback($expr, $callback, $subject);
}
```

**What does that do?**

*In a nutshell:*

- Create a regular expression using the specified escape character that will match one of three sequences (more on that below)
- Feed that into [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback), where the callback handles two of those sequences exactly and treats everything else as a replacement operation.
- Return the resulting string

*The regex*

The regex matches any one of these three sequences:

- Two occurrences of the escape character, followed by zero or more occurrences of the escape character, followed by an opening curly brace. Only the first two occurrences of the escape character are consumed. This is replaced by a single occurrence of the escape character.
- A single occurrence of the escape character followed by an opening curly brace. This is replaced by a literal open curly brace.
- An opening curly brace, followed by one or more perl word characters (alpha-numerics and the underscore character) followed by a closing curly brace. This is treated as a placeholder and a lookup is performed for the name between the braces in the `$variables` array, if it is found then return the replacement value, if not then return the value of `$errPlaceholder` - by default this is `null`, which is treated as a special case and the original placeholder is returned (i.e. the string is not modified).

**Why is it better?**

To understand why it's better, let's look at the replacement approaches take by other answers. With [one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197348/replacing-variables-in-a-string/18198235#18198235) (the only failing of which is compatibility with PHP<5.4 and slightly non-obvious behaviour), these fall into two categories:

- [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) - This provides no mechanism for handling an escape character. What if your input string needs a literal `{X}` in it? `strtr()` does not account for this, and it would be substituted for the value `$X`.
- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) - this suffers from the same issue as `strtr()`, and another problem as well. When you call `str_replace()` with an array argument for the search/replace arguments, it behaves as if you had called it multiple times - one for each of the array of replacement pairs. This means that if one of your replacement strings contains a value that appears later in the search array, you will end up substituting that as well.

To demonstrate this issue with `str_replace()`, consider the following code:

```php
$pairs = array('A' => 'B', 'B' => 'C');
echo str_replace(array_keys($pairs), array_values($pairs), 'AB');
```

Now, you'd probably expect the output here to be `BC` but it will actually be `CC` ([demo](http://codepad.org/INyaTIsU)) - this is because the first iteration replaced `A` with `B`, and in the second iteration the subject string was `BB` - so both of these occurrences of `B` were replaced with `C`.

This issue also betrays a performance consideration that might not be immediately obvious - because each pair is handled separately, the operation is `O(n)`, for each replacement pair the entire string is searched and the single replacement operation handled. If you had a very large subject string and a lot of replacement pairs, that's a sizeable operation going on under the bonnet.

Arguably this performance consideration is a non-issue - you would need a *very* large string and a *lot* of replacement pairs before you got a meaningful slowdown, but it's still worth remembering. It's also worth remembering that regex has performance penalties of its own, so in general this consideration shouldn't be included in the decision-making process.

Instead we use `preg_replace_callback()`. This visits any given part of the string looking for matches exactly once, within the bounds of the supplied regular expression. I add this qualifier because if you write an expression that causes [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) then it will be considerably more than once, but in this case that shouldn't be a problem (to help avoid this I made the only repetition in the expression [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)).

We use `preg_replace_callback()` instead of `preg_replace()` to allow us to apply custom logic while looking for the replacement string.

**What this allows you to do**

*The original example from the question*

```
$X = 'Dany';
$Y = 'Stack Overflow';
$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y}';

echo parse($lang['example']);
```

This becomes:

```
$pairs = array(
    'X' = 'Dany',
    'Y' = 'Stack Overflow',
);

$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y}';

echo parse($lang['example'], $pairs);
// Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow
```

*Something more advanced*

Now let's say we have:

```
$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y} and it contained {X}';
// Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow and it contained Dany
```

...and we want the second `{X}` to appear *literally* in the resulting string. Using the default escape character of `@`, we would change it to:

```
$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y} and it contained @{X}';
// Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow and it contained {X}
```

OK, looks good so far. But what if that `@` was supposed to be a literal?

```
$lang['example'] = '{X} created a thread on {Y} and it contained @@{X}';
// Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow and it contained @Dany
```

Note that the regular expression has been designed to only pay attention to escape sequences that *immediately precede* an opening curly brace. This means that you don't need to escape the escape character unless it appears immediately in front of a placeholder.

**A note about the use of an array as an argument**

Your original code sample uses variables named the same way as the placeholders in the string. Mine uses an array with named keys. There are two very good reasons for this:

1. Clarity and security - it's much easier to see what will end up being substituted, and you don't risk accidentally substituting variables you don't want to be exposed. It wouldn't be much good if someone could simply feed in `{dbPass}` and see your database password, now would it?
2. Scope - it's not possible to import variables from the calling scope unless the caller is the global scope. This makes the function useless if called from another function, and importing data from another scope is very bad practice.

If you *really* want to use named variables from the current scope (and I do **not** recommend this due to the aforementioned security issues) you can pass the result of a call to [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/get-defined-vars) to the second argument.

**A note about choosing an escape character**

You'll notice I chose `@` as the default escape character. You can use any character (or sequence of characters, it can be more than one) by passing it to the third argument - and you may be tempted to use `\` since that's what many languages use, *but hold on before you do that*.

The reason you don't want to use `\` is *because* many languages use it as their own escape character, which means that when you want to specify your escape character in, say, a PHP string literal, you run into this problem:

```
$lang['example'] = '\\{X}';   // results in {X}
$lang['example'] = '\\\{X}';  // results in \Dany
$lang['example'] = '\\\\{X}'; // results in \Dany
```

It can lead to a readability nightmare, and some non-obvious behaviour with complex patterns. Pick an escape character that is not used by any other language involved (for example, if you are using this technique to generate fragments of HTML, don't use `&` as an escape character either).

**To sum up**

What you are doing has edge-cases. To solve the problem properly, you need to use a tool capable of handling those edge-cases - and when it comes to string manipulation, the tool for the job is most often regex.

Comment: Excellent answer, contains all the detailed explanation i was looking for, thanks for sharing your experience, and especially the part about Why it's better, i really appreciate the time you put into writing this :)

Comment: This seems to be to much to just replace the strings ... IMHO

Comment: @t1gor If all you want is string replacements, use `str_replace()`. But if you want a proper templating system then there are too many edge cases that `str_replace()` just cannot cope with.

Comment: @DaveRandom You are most probably right. But if we are talking of the template system, I would consider OOP concepts and `include()`-ing template files. I have some-thing like that in my project: https://bitbucket.org/t1gor/strategy/src/4568202177890480e4cc0268b4458889bc6bf0ae/application/core/Template.php?at=default

Answer (score 12):

Here's a portable solution, using variable variables. Yay!

```
$string = "I need to replace {X} and {Y}";
$X = 'something';
$Y = 'something else';

preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/', $string, $matches);           

foreach ($matches[1] as $value)
{
    $string = str_replace('{'.$value.'}', ${$value}, $string);
}
```

First you set up your string, and your replacements. Then, you perform a regular expression to get an array of matches (strings within { and }, including those brackets). Finally, you loop around these and replace those with the variables you created above, using variable variables. Lovely!

---

Just thought I'd update this with another option even though you've marked it as correct. You don't *have* to use variable variables, and an array can be used in it's place.

```
$map = array(
    'X' => 'something',
    'Y' => 'something else'
);

preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/', $string, $matches);           

foreach ($matches[1] as $value)
{
    $string = str_replace('{'.$value.'}', $map[$value], $string);
}
```

That would allow you to create a function with the following signature:

```
public function parse($string, $map); // Probably what I'd do tbh
```

---

Another option thanks to toolmakersteve in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197348/replacing-variables-in-a-string/18197743?noredirect=1#comment98342718_18197743) does away with the need for a loop and uses [strtr](https://php.net/strtr), but requires minor additions to the variables and single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$string = 'I need to replace {$X} and {$Y}';

$map = array(
    '{$X}' => 'something',
    '{$Y}' => 'something else'
);

$string = strtr($string, $map);
```

Comment: PERFECT thanks! ill just wrap this into a class/function :) should i have any concerns performance wise considering you're using a RE ?

Comment: It's a really simple regex, I can't see any issue here. If you're really worried, run some performance tests, but there's no point micro-optimising - it'll be fine.

Comment: great thanks, also good point about the scope of the variables :D

Comment: Yeah I removed that - this is good enough ;) didn't want to go too in-depth ;)

Comment: This will work great up until the point at which you need to use `{}` somewhere within the template...

Comment: @zzzzBov Perhaps this is a limitation of the option chosen by OP as he asked this question? Although I do agree, it should be something like `%%variable%%` as that would be much more uncommon.

Comment: yup true, i'll go with `%%` as suggested, i hate discovering surprises later :D

Comment: @zzzzBov Updated with another option just in-case. You still need to add your checks obviously to make sure the variables you're asking for exist etc...

Comment: Would [strtr](https://php.net/strtr) perform a similar replacement, without needing a `foreach` loop?  [second option in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065420/199364)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This is an option also, with small changes. I'll add it as an option!

Answer (score 4):

If you're running 5.4 and you care about being able to use PHP's builtin variable interpolation in the string, you can use the `bindTo()` method of `Closure` like so:

```
// Strings use interpolation, but have to return themselves from an anon func
$strings = [
    'en' => [
        'message_sent' => function() { return "You just sent a message to $this->recipient that said: $this->message."; }
    ],
    'es' => [
        'message_sent' => function() { return "Acabas de enviar un mensaje a $this->recipient que dijo: $this->message."; }
    ]
];

class LocalizationScope {
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($param) {
        if(isset($this->data[$param])) {
            return $this->data[$param];
        }

        return '';
    }
}

// Bind the string anon func to an object of the array data passed in and invoke (returns string)
function localize($stringCb, $data) {
    return $stringCb->bindTo(new LocalizationScope($data))->__invoke();
}

// Demo
foreach($strings as $str) {
    var_dump(localize($str['message_sent'], array(
        'recipient' => 'Jeff Atwood',
        'message' => 'The project should be done in 6 to 8 weeks.'
    )));
}

//string(93) "You just sent a message to Jeff Atwood that said: The project should be done in 6 to 8 weeks."
//string(95) "Acabas de enviar un mensaje a Jeff Atwood que dijo: The project should be done in 6 to 8 weeks."
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7fJJOP))

Perhaps, it feels a bit hacky, and I don't particularly like using `$this` in this instance. But you do get the added benefit of relying on PHP's variable interpolation (which allows you to do things like escaping, that are difficult to achieve with regex).

---

**EDIT:** Added `LocalizationScope`, which adds another benefit: no warnings if localization anonymous functions try to access data that was not provided.

Comment: great answer! this was exactly what i was looking for but unfortunately i am running 5.3 :( so thats the reason why i wouldn't mark your answer as the chosen one :)

Comment: This is actually really clever (+1), but it took me a good minute or so of reading it before I could really see what it was doing (mostly because of the `$this` issue you mentioned yourself). I would steer away from this on the grounds of non-obvious behaviour, but at the same this is mechanically a great and very flexible solution to the problem.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks! I agree about the `$this` issue. When I first wrote the code, I omitted it (assuming a more javascript-esque scope bind) and soon found that that didn't work. If there was a way to late bind `use` variables, this could be more intuitive, but for now I completely agree about the non-obviousness of the `$this`.

Answer (score 2):

[`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) is probably a better choice for this kind of things, because it replaces longest keys first:

```
$repls = array(
  'X' => 'Dany',
  'Y' => 'Stack Overflow',
);

foreach($data as $key => $value)
  $repls['{' . $key . '}'] = $value;

$result = strtr($text, $repls);
```

(think of situations where you have keys like XX and X)

---

And if you don't want to use an array and instead expose all variables from the current scope:

```
$repls = get_defined_vars();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your only issue with sprintf is the order of the arguments you can use argument swapping.

From the doc (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$format = 'The %2$s contains %1$d monkeys';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
```

Comment: Why was this was voted down? Seems the obvious answer to me. While the order can change from language to language, you know the order when writing the template string. To use the OP example "%1$s created a thread on %2$s" or "%2$s has a new post by %1$s" or whatever are supported by sprintf($template_string, 'Dany', 'StackOverflow'). It is exactly how many systems solve translations (e.g. Wordpress uses gettext and recommends passing your gettext string through printf in exactly this way if you need parameters in the string) http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders

Comment: OK.  I see the OP wants the variables named exactly so.  Since that needs documenting for each string anyway, I'm not convinced it's worth it.  Since he also said that he cosnidered sprintf but discounted it because of the ordering problem then I think this is still a valid answer

Answer (score 2):

**gettext** is a widely used universal localization system that does exactly what you want.
There are libraries for most programming languages and **PHP** has a **built-in engine**.
It is driven by po-files, simple text based format, for which there are many editors around and it is compatible with sprintf syntax.

It even has some functions to deal with things like complicated plurals that some languages have.

Here are some examples of what it does. Note that _() is an alias for gettext():

- `echo _('Hello world');` // will output hello world in the current selected language
- `echo sprintf(_("%s has created a thread on %s"), $name, $site);` // translates the string, and hands it over to sprintf()
- `echo sprintf(_("%2$s has created a thread on %1$s"), $site, $name);` // same as above, but with changed order of parameters.

If you have more than a handful of strings, you should definitely use an existing engine, rather than writing your own one.
Adding a new language is just a matter of translating a list of strings and most professional translation tools can work with this file format, too.

Check Wikipedia and the PHP documentation for a basic overview on how this works:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext
- http://de.php.net/gettext

Google finds heaps of documentation and your favourite software repository will most likely have a handful of tools for managing po-files.

Some that I have used are:

- **poedit**: Very light and simple. Good if you don't have too much stuff to translate and don't want to spend time thinking about how that stuff works.
- **Virtaal**: A bit more complex and has a bit of a learning curve, but also some nice features that make your life easier. Good if you need to translate a lot.
- **GlotPress** is a web application (from the wordpress people) that allows collaborative editing of the translation database files.

Comment: Is gettext best as compare to xml? IS it send request to server for translation of every msgid?

Comment: No, it has nothing in common with XML. And it does not send any requests at runtime. It's pretty much a collection of strings that are set for each language.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use str_replace then? If you want it as template.

```
echo str_replace(array('{X}', '{Y}'), array($X, $Y), $lang['example']);
```

for every occurrence of this that you need

str_replace was built for this in the first place.

Comment: i am just looking for a more portable solution

Comment: What do you mean by more portable, str_replace works on all OS's that php runs on?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by more portable?

Comment: i mean that it doesn't require passing all 3 parameters on every call and just takes 1 which is the string

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$X = 'Dany';
$Y = 'Stack Overflow';
$lang['example'] = "{$X} created a thread on {$Y}";
```

Hence:

```
echo $lang['example'];
```

Will output:

```
Dany created a thread on Stack Overflow
```

As you requested.

**UPDATE:**

As per the OP's comments about making the solution more portable:

Have a class do the parsing for you each time:

```
class MyParser {
  function parse($vstr) {
    return "{$x} created a thread on {$y}";
  }
}
```

That way, if the following occurs:

```
$X = 3;
$Y = 4;

$a = new MyParser();
$lang['example'] = $a->parse($X, $Y);

echo $lang['example'];
```

Which will return:

```
3 created a thread on 4;
```

And, double checking:

```
$X = 'Steve';
$Y = 10.9;

$lang['example'] = $a->parse($X, $Y);
```

Will print:

```
Steve created a thread on 10.9;
```

As desired.

**UPDATE 2:**

As per the OP's comments about improving portability:

```
class MyParser {
  function parse($vstr) {
    return "{$vstr}";
  }
}

$a = new MyParser();

$X = 3;
$Y = 4;
$vstr = "{$X} created a thread on {$Y}";

$a = new MyParser();
$lang['example'] = $a->parse($vstr);

echo $lang['example'];
```

Will output the results cited previously.

Comment: please check my comment on RiggsFolly's answer

Comment: interesting! one downside though, from what i can see this requires me to create a method for each template that contains variables

Comment: @DanyKhalife: not necessarily. I've updated my answer again to reflect that while my implementation is a naive one, you can generalize it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$lang['example'] = "$X created a thread on $Y";
```

EDIT: Based on latest info

Maybe you need to look at the sprintf() function

Then you could have your template string defined as this

```
$template_string = '%s created a thread on %s';


$X = 'Fred';
$Y = 'Sunday';

echo sprintf( $template_string, $X, $Y );
```

`$template_string` does not change but later in your code when you have assigned different values to `$X` and `$Y` you can still use the `echo sprintf( $template_string, $X, $Y );`

[See PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that $X and $Y aren't known when this string is initialised

Comment: to make it more clear: this basically initialises the string with the current values of X and Y but in case i would like to reuse this string template, i can't...

Comment: could you maybe set a condition for a `$_SESSION` variable?

Comment: it still won't solve the problem. To illustrate my point, lets say `$X = 1, $Y = 2; echo $lang['example'];` Then `$X = 3, $Y = 4; echo $lang['example'];`. Both these `echo`s shouldn't be the same because $X and $Y changed values (that's why i said i probably need to call a function on this string before each echo).

Comment: thanks for your support but from what i know sprintf requires that the variables be in a specific order which isn't something i am certain of when switching languages :)

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the "variable" parts as an array with keys corresponding to the placeholders in your string?

```
$string = "{X} created a thread on {Y}";
$values = array(
   'X' => "Danny",
   'Y' => "Stack Overflow",
);

echo str_replace(
   array_map(function($v) { return '{'.$v.'}'; }, array_keys($values)),
   array_values($values),
   $string
);
```

Comment: you definitely got my attention with your array_map :) but i'd like to wait a bit and see if someone has a way to do that which doesn't require passing the array of variables on each call

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use the template string within a function?

```
function threadTemplate($x, $y) {
    return "{$x} created a thread on {$y}";
}
echo threadTemplate($foo, $bar);
```

Comment: because i'll have to create a function for each template, this will get out of control in no time :)

Answer (score 0):

just throwing another solution in using associative arrays. This will loop through the associative array and either replace the template or leave it blank.

example:

```
$list = array();
$list['X'] = 'Dany';
$list['Y'] = 'Stack Overflow';

$str = '{X} created a thread on {Y}';

$newstring = textReplaceContent($str,$list);


    function textReplaceContent($contents, $list) {


                while (list($key, $val) = each($list)) {
                    $key = "{" . $key . "}";
                    if ($val) {
                        $contents = str_replace($key, $val, $contents);
                    } else {
                        $contents = str_replace($key, "", $contents);
                    }
                }
                $final = preg_replace('/\[\w+\]/', '', $contents);

                return ($final);
            }
```

Comment: Zzzz Zzzzz Zzzzz zzZZzzzz :)