# PHP HTML {$variable}

Tags: php, html, variables

How can i print variable in brackets? Like ip board, for example I have this code:

```
<?php
$variable = "test";
?>
<div class="test">{$variable}</div>
```

How can I do this? Not

> echo $variable;?>

but {$variable} ! Thanks in advance :3

Comment: <?php echo $variable;?>

Comment: I know it.. but I wan't {$variable}

Comment: you want to show a variable without echoing it, oh. so what does "Not echo...." mean?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print `{test}` or you want the `{}` to cause the data to be printed?

Comment: {} to cause the data to be printed

Comment: You can't do that with raw PHP. You need some other library with such syntax.

Comment: @Evaldas777 I think you are looking for a template-engine, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twig/info Otherwise you somehow need to let PHP process your file

Comment: this question's clearer than mud at midnight

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing variables in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18197348)

Answer (score 3):

It's called concatenation and it uses '.' to string things together...

```
<div class="test"><?php echo '{'.$variable.'}' ?></div>
```

Comment: Are you kidding? I wan't to print variable value with {$variable} not with echo....

Comment: *"Are you kidding?"* - question is... are "you" kidding? @Evaldas777

Comment: Are you kidding? You said "print variable IN brackets".  Sorry, for trying to help with a poorly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this

```
<?= $variable ?>
```

Comment: Nope... I wan't {$variable}

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can just do it like

```
<?php
    $variable = "test";
?>
<div class="test"><?= $variable; ?></div>
```

but if you want to use above approach(your one) you've to use `blade templating engine`

[have a look](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/256/assigning-a-variable-in-a-blade-template)

Comment: Nope... I wan't {$variable}

Comment: you've to use `blade` for that, may be you can start with `Laravel` to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Use a php templating engine. Best for you is that use Laravel and Balde

Comment: yeah [someone said that here....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764602/php-html-variable#comment51461364_31764631)

Comment: **or** create your own `templating system`
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/roll-your-own-templating-system-in-php--net-16596