# PHP double quote string parser

Tags: php, parsing, double-quotes

PHP of course performs variable replacement on double quoted strings:

```
$test = 'something';
echo "This is a $test";
//Output: This is a something
```

What I'm looking for is PHP's variable replacement but with callback:

```
function callback($key, &$value) {
    $value=strtoupper($value);
}

$test = 'something';
echo some_cool_function('This is a $test', callback);

//Output: This is a SOMETHING
```

(Of course that was a totally arbitrary example - I am not looking to do something as simple as converting values to uppercase.)

Thus `callback` would then be called for each variable (or perhaps with an array of all variables like `'$test' => 'something'`).  That way I can directly manipulate and otherwise work with the variables and replacement values PHP performs.

I know something similar can be done with regular expressions with callback and the like.  However, there is extra complexity in how PHP handles variables like `$test[0]`, complex syntax (`{ }`), etc that may be convoluted to work with.

Does PHP expose its internal string parser used for double quoted strings in some way?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you'd want to do. Do you mean like a for statement looping through variables? for example: `$test = ['test1', 'test2']; foreach ($test as $val){ $testString = "this is a $val"; some_cool_function( $testString); }`

Comment: The double quote string handling isn't exposed by itself. You'll have to [consider eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197348/replacing-variables-in-a-string), or use a more reasonable regex for substituting array and complex variables, or make `{$…}` complex variable names [or `{…}` markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197348/replacing-variables-in-a-string) a dependency.

Comment: I have updated my question with a more detailed example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I suggest using `preg_replace_callback()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you intending that `some_cool_function` would apply the function `callback` to the string `'This is a $test'`.

Referencing the callback function by using a variable will do the trick:

```
$cb = callback;
$test = 'something';
echo "This is a {$cb($test)}";
```