# Variable into another variable

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a variable ($uid) which fetches value from a database. My problem is that I am not able to append that variable to another variable ($str). The value of the $uid will be in place of '___' in the $str variable. How do I do approach?

```
$uid = 5;
$str ='ALPHA|___|NA|2|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|NA|BETA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA';
```

Comment: Read about `str_replace();`  `echo str_replace('___',$uid,$str);`

Comment: str_replace('__', $uid, $str);

Comment: Did you do _any_ research at all before asking? I'm pretty sure a simple search for "replace a string in PHP" would have given you an answer faster than it took you to write this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How replace variable in string with value in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-replace-variable-in-string-with-value-in-php)

Comment: If you changed the quotes - you could use `$str ="ALPHA|$uid|NA|..."`, just make sure you use double quotes rather than single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this code 
$uid = 5; $str ='ALPHA|___|NA|2|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|NA|BETA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA';
echo str_replace("___",$uid,$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
`$uid = 5;`

`$str ='ALPHA|___|NA|2|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|NA|BETA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA';`

`echo str_replace("___",$uid,$str);`

output : ALPHA|5|NA|2|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|NA|BETA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA

Comment: That is ok but my main purpose is to calculate checksums for the $str variable with the $uid variable in place of ___. I don't want to output the value