# php how to parse variable substitution without printing

Tags: php, string, laravel, variables, substitution

how to parse variable inside string?

here is a sample code that works:

```
$str =  "12345";
$str2 = "STR:{$str}";
$str3 = $str2;
echo $str2;
echo $str3;
```

but these won't work:

```
$otp = 12345;
$template = MessageTemplate::where('type',1)->first(); //db query
$message = $template->content; //content field, "OTP:{$otp}" 
echo $message;
```

this code prints `OTP:{$otp}` instead of `OTP:12345`

these is what we need:
    
    `$member = Member::where('id',$id)->with('position')->with('company')->first();
    $otp = 12345;
    $template = MessageTemplate::where('type',1)->first(); //db query
    $message = $template->content; //content field, "OTP:{$otp}" 
    $sms = Sms::Create(['mobile'=>$member->mobile,'message'=>$message]);`

this code prints `OTP:{$otp}` instead of `OTP:12345`

Thanks for your responses. Actually what i need is to parse it before saving it to the database. the string "OTP:12345" should be written back to the databse. and also, variables are dynamic. It is a template to allow admin to customize the message, so the admin can add as many variable as he/she want. For ex: 
"{$member->title},{$member->firstName}, {$member->lastName}, in order to verify that you are {$mamber->position->name} of {$member->company->name}. enter code {$otp}".

so i can't use str_replace. and also our db supports json so admin can add a custom attribute to $member

Comment: $otp = "12345"; try with string.

Comment: `str_replace/preg_replace` only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace a variable in a string with the value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065387/how-can-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-string-with-the-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutators in your model like this

```
// MessageTemplate class
public function getContentAttribute($string)
{
    return 'OTP:' . $string;
}

// anywhere in controller
$message = $template->content; // will call content mutator
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of $template->content is just a string.

You can simply do a replace:

```
$message = str_replace('{$otp}', $otp, $template->content);
```